# How registered COM interface is linked to twapi moniker?

Tags: c#, com, tcl

I want to use c# code app in tcl using COM > twapi > tcl path.
By studying ["call c# code from tcl"](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17644) wiki page I understood two things.
We need to compile c# code with com interface register VS option. Then use that namespacename.classname to create object instance. But it is not clear how twapi (or tcom) will use that com (or link). Can you please explain in more details. Thanking you in advance.

---

C# code

```
using System;
 namespace MyClassLib
 {
    public class Class1
    {
    public Class1()   {}
    public int Double (int val)  { return val * 2 ;  }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the project is registered for COM Interop and built, the class is registered in the system's Registry as a provider for that class name. The tcom package knows how to use that information. When you do:

```
set myCom [tcom::ref createobject "ClassLibrary1.Class1"]
```

It goes away and asks the COM service that's built into Windows to make an instance of that object and give a reference to it back to you. That reference is what is stored in the variable. You can then invoke methods of the object; the syntax for that is Tcl-ish rather than C#-ish, but the models line up.

```
$myCom Double 6
```

Yes, there's a lot of complexity going on behind the scenes, mostly centred on [`IDispatch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDispatch) and its related interfaces.

Comment: How tcom knows the path of the code (dll or exe). Or is it copies the compiled code into windows somewhere so that windows com program can access through some kind of "key" code in registry?